# App working with large arrays "stops working", but still continues to print Log messages to AndroidStudio

Tags: android, arrays, crash

I'm writing code that performs a projective transform (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/296794/finding-the-transform-matrix-from-4-projected-points-with-javascript) on an image using 4 user selected points.

In doing so I have to use very large arrays (300k+ indices). When I run it, my phone screen blacks out and after a few seconds gives the message " has stopped working." However, it continues to print Log messages to my AndroidStudio logcat containing information about the array that it's working on, letting me know that it's still running.

I'm not very knowledgeable about computational efficiency, so I might be making some fatal mistake involving matrix manipulation. The part of the code that it breaks on is the final portion of transform(), and the logcat prints the "rounded" values while the phone shows a "stopped working" message.

I've included the relevant code. Any advice on anything I'm doing wrong (related or not) is appreciated as this is my first experience with Android development.

I'm more or less just following the transformation provided by in the math.stackexchange link.

```
public class projTransform extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_proj_transform);

    Intent parent_intent = getIntent();
    Uri imgUri = parent_intent.getData();
    pointArray = parent_intent.getDoubleArrayExtra("points");
    //dimens[0-3]: width, height, minX, minY
    dimens = parent_intent.getIntArrayExtra("dimens");
    transform(imgUri,pointArray, dimens);
}
//A*B = C
private static double[][] mMult(double[][] A, double[][] B){
    int mA = A.length;
    int nA = A[0].length;
    int mB = B.length;
    int nB = B[0].length;
    if (nA != mB) throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");
    double[][] C = new double[mA][nB];
        for (int i = 0; i < mA; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < nB; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < nA; k++)
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
    return C;
}
//A*x = y
private static double[] mMult(double[][] A, double[] x){
    int m = A.length;
    int n = A[0].length;
    if (x.length != n) throw new RuntimeException("Illegal matrix dimensions.");
    double[] y = new double[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            y[i] += A[i][j] * x[j];
    return y;
}
//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3.C3.973_matrices
//A^(-1)
private static double[][] mInvert3x3(double[][] X){
    double[][] Y = new double[3][3];
    double A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,detX;
    A =   X[1][1]*X[2][2] - X[1][2]*X[2][1];
    B = -(X[1][0]*X[2][2] - X[1][2]*X[2][0]);
    C =   X[1][0]*X[2][1] - X[1][1]*X[2][0];
    D = -(X[0][1]*X[2][2] - X[0][2]*X[2][1]);
    E =   X[0][0]*X[2][2] - X[0][2]*X[2][0];
    F = -(X[0][0]*X[2][1] - X[0][1]*X[2][0]);
    G =   X[0][1]*X[1][2] - X[0][2]*X[1][1];
    H = -(X[0][0]*X[1][2] - X[0][2]*X[1][0]);
    I =   X[0][0]*X[1][1] - X[0][1]*X[1][0];
    detX = X[0][0]*A + X[0][1]*B + X[0][2]*C;

    Y[0][0] = A/detX;
    Y[1][0] = B/detX;
    Y[2][0] = C/detX;
    Y[0][1] = D/detX;
    Y[1][1] = E/detX;
    Y[2][1] = F/detX;
    Y[0][2] = G/detX;
    Y[1][2] = H/detX;
    Y[2][2] = I/detX;

    return Y;
}

private void transform(Uri data, double[] sourceArray, int[] dimens){

    if (data != null) {
        try {
            InputStream imgStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data);
            tempBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imgStream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap rotatedbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tempBmp, 0, 0, tempBmp.getWidth(), tempBmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);

        crop = new int[dimens[0] * dimens[1]];
        rotatedbmp.getPixels(crop, 0, dimens[0], dimens[2], dimens[3], dimens[0], dimens[1]);

        //map for original bmp
        double[][] sourceMap = tMap(sourceArray);
        Log.e("sourceMap",toString(sourceMap));

        //map for transformed bmp
        double[] destArray = new double[] {0,0,0,destHeight,destWidth,0,destHeight,destWidth};
        double[][] destMap = tMap(destArray);
        Log.e("destMap",toString(destMap));

        // C = B*[A^(-1)]
        double[][] finalMap = mMult(sourceMap, mInvert3x3(destMap));

        Log.e("width", String.valueOf(dimens[0]));

        int[] destPixels = new int[destHeight*destWidth];
        int[] temp;
        for(int i=0; i<destHeight-1; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<destWidth-1; j++){
                temp = pixelMap(finalMap,i,j);
                Log.e("rounded", String.valueOf(temp[0]) + ", " + String.valueOf(temp[1]));
                destPixels[(i*destWidth)+j] = crop[(temp[0]*dimens[0]) + temp[1]];
            }
        }
        display(destPixels, destWidth, destHeight);
    }
}

//produces mapping matrix given corners
//A,B in SE post
private double[][] tMap(double[] pointArray){
    double[][] tempArray = new double[3][3];
    tempArray[0][0] = pointArray[0];
    tempArray[1][0] = pointArray[1];
    tempArray[0][1] = pointArray[2];
    tempArray[1][1] = pointArray[3];
    tempArray[0][2] = pointArray[4];
    tempArray[1][2] = pointArray[5];
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        tempArray[2][i] = 1;
    }
    //Log.e("tempArray",toString(tempArray));

    double[] tempVector = new double[] {pointArray[6], pointArray[7], 1};

    //Log.e("tempVector",toString(tempVector));

    double[][] inverted = mInvert3x3(tempArray);

    //Log.e("inverted",toString(inverted));

    double[] coef = mMult(inverted, tempVector);

    //Log.e("coef",toString(coef));

    double[][] tran = new double[3][3];

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++){
            tran[i][j] = tempArray[i][j]*coef[j];
        }
    }
    return tran;
}

private int[] pixelMap(double[][] map, double x, double y){
    double[] tempVector = new double[] {x,y,1};
    double[] primeVector = mMult(map,tempVector);
    return new int[] {(int) Math.round(primeVector[0]/primeVector[2]), (int) Math.round(primeVector[1]/primeVector[2])};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to divide by the determinant; the adjoint instead of the inverse is sufficient. Apart form that, you're creating a lot of objects.

The tight loop is one with the two nested loops around the `pixelMap` call. Try to inline `pixelMap` there, and try to avoid creating new arrays. Use separate variables for all the infividual coordinates. Use the fact that you know the dimensions.

```
x = finalMap[0][0]*i + finalMap[0][1]*j + finalMap[0][2];
```

and so on. If you want to, you can move `finalMap` into a set of 9 local variables to help the optimizer. Also disable the logging line, since caching and transfering that much log output takes considerable resources. Do one log line when you start the loop, and another when you're done. In the end, the loop would look somewhat like this:

```
    for(int i=0; i<destHeight-1; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<destWidth-1; j++){
            double x = finalMap00*i + finalMap01*j + finalMap02;
            double y = finalMap10*i + finalMap11*j + finalMap12;
            double z = finalMap20*i + finalMap21*j + finalMap22;
            int xi = (int)Math.round(x/z), yi = (int)Math.round(y/z);
            destPixels[(i*destWidth)+j] = crop[(xi*srcWidth) + yi];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Thanks for the clear answer. What would be the best way to test how much of an improvement this is, efficiency wise?

Comment: @delphiki: I'd say compare time spent in this method before and after the modification, with the same input. But you can certainly research tools for this using a search engine or, lacking suitable answers there, ask a separate questions about performance evaluations in Android.